# Code organisation and scenes in corona. What to put where?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm relatively new to corona sdk and was wondering about the best way to organise my code. I have some basic sprites that have some simple animations and I've been playing around with scenes to try and create a main menu and playing area. For stuff like setting sprite sequences and sprite options should I be doing this in another module and then calling it? Does that only matter if I have multiple levels?

Also what should I be declaring within main.lua? Just global variables? Or is this where I could do all my sprite stuff?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out

- [Match Three Space RPG Game Template Series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLhE_IYaXVf9skwhKXNswj0C9U3RZB3DaD) - Walk through a free match three game template with a space RPG theme. This project was developed by Ponywolf for the Corona community. 
  [coronalabs/Match-Three-Space-RPG](https://github.com/coronalabs/Match-Three-Space-RPG) on Github,
- [Sticker Knight Game Design - Brainstorming Ideas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDrCxp-Dx0s) - Michael Wilson from Ponywolf shares insights into the creative game design process his team uses to come up with games like Sticker Knight, Time Golf Squad, and Skipchaser and other great games. Once the planning is finished, the Ponywolf team uses Corona SDK to bring their ideas to life. Corona is a cross platform mobile SDK that makes it easy for developers to create native games and apps for iOS, Android, Kindle, Windows Phone, Apple TV, Android TV, and Mac and Windows desktops. [coronalabs/Sticker-Knight-Platformer](https://github.com/coronalabs/Sticker-Knight-Platformer) on Github.

Read [Goodbye Globals!](https://docs.coronalabs.com/tutorial/basics/globals/index.html) from Corona doumentation to know more about global variables.

To better organize your code use modules. Read more about it in [External Modules in Corona](https://docs.coronalabs.com/tutorial/basics/externalModules/index.html).